# Sending SMS from Java mail through Exchange 2010: content limited to 75 characters

Tags: java, sms, exchange-server, sendmail

I've written the necessary code to send an e-Mail to my Exchange 2010 server that will be forwarded to the SMS Gateway to a mobile phone. I did change all the user, host and other relevant data for this post, but the code works fine, I receive the SMS. (So the Exchange side config is OK) The only problem is that my SMS content is cut off after 75 characters.

I've read that MimeMessage headers can't be longer then those 75 chars, but what I'm sending isn't the header (aka subject, it's the body (aka content)? Anyway, I tried to get around other restrictions like 78 chars in a line, trying to use anything that comes to my mind that could do a CR and/or LF (\n\r, (char)10+(char)13), the SMS content is still cut off after 75 characters.

I have a workaround that would simply send multiple SMSes, truncating the body into as many messages as needed, but if there's another way to get longer texts send out in one piece I would be glad to know.

Here is my actual code:

```
    String host = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String user = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String passwd = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("This is supposed to be a very long message to try how many characters I can send from Java as SMS through Exchange. Is it long enough? Cause it will cut at 75 characters. ");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.from", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");

    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"));
        message.setContent(body.toString(), "text/plain");
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, 25, user, passwd);
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm, just tried to send it to my e-Mail Adress instead of mobile, in that case I receive the whole message in Outlook. That would mean it's no Java related problem. Otos, if I send a message from my Outlook to the mobile, I can also use more than 75 characters, so that would mean it's also no Exchange or SMS Gateway related problem.......

Comment: There are 2 receive connectors in Exchange, one for the SMS Gateway, one to allow incoming SMTP(for Java), both have the same config with a 10240kb message size, so it doesn't look like the problem comes from them.